# Python/Flask works in development but not in Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have no idea what is going on. The architecture is that a Spring Boot (Java) backend sends the request (image) to another Spring Boot server which sends it to Flask to predict if it is a cat or dog. When I manually start every server it works fine. But as one docker complex (docker-compose) only in this cat or dog method flask fails somehow. It's the same method. We also got a OCR method where we do the exactly same thing in Spring Boot and it works fine. So it has to be something with the Flask and this method... but what?

```
@app.route('/cat-or-dog/predict', methods=['POST'])
def image_classifier_cat_or_dog():
    img_codes = json.loads(request.form['images'])

    # Decoding base64 images
    imgs = []
    for img_code in img_codes:
        imgs.append(image.img_to_array(image.load_img(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(img_code)),
                                                      target_size=(150, 150, 3))))

    # Pre-processing images
    X_imgs = preprocess_images(imgs)
    X_imgs = np.array(X_imgs)
    n_imgs = len(X_imgs)

    # Predicting content of images
    predictions = []
    i = 0
    for batch in datagen.flow(X_imgs, batch_size=1):
        pred = model.predict(batch)
        if pred > 0.5:
            predictions.append("dog")
        else:
            predictions.append("cat")
        i += 1
        if i % n_imgs == 0:
            break

    return jsonify(predictions=predictions)

# Image preprocessing for cat or dog classifier


def preprocess_images(new_imgs):
    X = []

    for img in new_imgs:
        X.append(cv2.resize(img, (150, 150), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))

    return X
```

The error:

```
aiproject-flask           | ERROR:app:Exception on /cat-or-dog/predict [POST]
aiproject-flask           | Traceback (most recent call last):
aiproject-flask           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
aiproject-flask           |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
aiproject-flask           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
aiproject-flask           |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
aiproject-flask           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
aiproject-flask           |     return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
aiproject-flask           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
aiproject-flask           |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
aiproject-flask           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
aiproject-flask           |     raise value
aiproject-flask           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
aiproject-flask           |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
aiproject-flask           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
aiproject-flask           |     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
aiproject-flask           |   File "/app/app.py", line 85, in image_classifier_cat_or_dog
aiproject-flask           |     target_size=(150, 150, 3))))
aiproject-flask           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 113, in load_img
aiproject-flask           |     with open(path, 'rb') as f:
aiproject-flask           | TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO
aiproject-flask           | INFO:werkzeug:172.30.0.2 - - [09/Jun/2020 17:45:12] "POST /cat-or-dog/predict HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Keras docs](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#loadimg-function), `load_img` function accepts only path-like objects, which is in line with the behavior You are experiencing.

You are attempting to serve some flask app inside container, right? Are You sure that You are using the same branch of code that runs just fine somewhere else?

Locate correct container name by looking at the output of:

```
docker container ls
```

With this, log in into container:

```
docker container exec -it <container_name> bash
```

Next, navigate to the application directory (assuming that You are using git here...):

```
cd /path/to/your/application/repository
```

And check the branch name in the output of:

```
git status
```

Then do the same, but inside original repository from which You are "manually starting every server". Compare this two outputs.

I am almost sure that You are using wrong codebase from outdated/not updated branch or something similar. Try to figure it out somehow.

If You are sure that You want to modify the code that You have presented, You should be able to fix that error by replacing following statement:

```
imgs.append(image.img_to_array(image.load_img(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(img_code)),
                                                      target_size=(150, 150, 3))))
```

with this:

```
# move this import somewere else...
from PIL import Image as PIL_Image


bytes_stream = BytesIO(base64.b64decode(img_code))
img = PIL_Image.open(bytes_stream)
img = img.convert('RGB')
img = img.resize((150, 150, 3), PIL_Image.NEAREST)

imgs.append(image.img_to_array(img))
```

Above change was proposed in [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11684#issuecomment-601142362) as a workaround for a very similar concern as Yours.